# how to mount a ufs filesytem with strictatime option

Tags: freebsd

How to mount a ufs filesystem with strictatime option. I didn't find the option in freebsd.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Linuxism. `strictatime` and `relatime` are not used on FreeBSD. Access time in general is rarely used in FreeBSD (mostly for mailboxes). Because of that you will often see people mount using "noatime" on FreeBSD.

The default is however to update the access time. You will then only set `noatime` when you do not want that.

This means that the default mount is the same as `strictatime` on Linux. See [mount](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mount&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)